# jQuery Mobile Fixed Toolbar Fade Out on Scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to mimic the following page in terms of the fixed header functionality.
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html

However, with the newer release of jquerymobile, I believe they removed that fade in/fade out functionality on scroll.

Is there a way with the new jquerymobile release to mimic that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `data-position="fixed"` toolbars then you should be able to add a couple `data-attributes` to the tag to allow "toggling" the toolbar:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-tap-toggle="true" data-transition="fade">
    ...
</div>
```

Documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed-options.html

That will work for taps, for scrolling I believe you have to use your own event handler:

```
//when a user starts to scroll, hide the toolbar(s)
$(window).bind('scrollstart', function () {
    $.mobile.activePage.children("[data-position='fixed']").fixedtoolbar('hide');

//when a user stops a scroll, show the toolbar(s)
}).bind('scrollstop', function () {
    $.mobile.activePage.children("[data-position='fixed']").fixedtoolbar('show');
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BCTpK/

After making the demo I realized that setting a timeout so that the `scrollstart` and `scrollstop` events don't fire too often is a good idea:

```
var timer = null;

//when a user starts to scroll, hide the toolbar(s)
$(window).bind('scrollstart', function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $.mobile.activePage.children("[data-position='fixed']").fixedtoolbar('hide');
    }, 100);

//when a user stops a scroll, show the toolbar(s)
}).bind('scrollstop', function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $.mobile.activePage.children("[data-position='fixed']").fixedtoolbar('show');
    }, 100);
});​
```

Comment: Does this $(window).bind event handler go within a 'pageshow', 'pageinit' , 'mobileinit' or document.ready function ?

Comment: It can be run in the global scope. `window` is always available, so just make sure you run this code after jQuery Core has loaded.

Comment: How about Headroom.js? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23880524/jquery-mobile-fixed-toolbars-with-headroom-js-disappear-reappear-on-scroll

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use this behavior for toolbars?

Then you can also check the JQM 1.1. [release notes](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/), it includes a link to a polyfill to use the old the fixed toolbar behavior.

Here is the [preview URL](http://filamentgroup.github.com/jQuery-Mobile-FixedToolbar-Legacy-Polyfill/) and [Github](https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-Mobile-FixedToolbar-Legacy-Polyfill) repo

If you want to use the behavior for some other elements (header/footer any element you like), I took a function from the polyfill to reposition on show() and am using it like this:

```
// reposition before showing - based on JQM fixedtoolbar polyfill   
var $popPanel = YOUR_ELEMENT(S) to be repositioned
$popPanel.jqmData("fixed") == "top" ? 
    $popPanel.css( "top", $( window ).scrollTop() + "px" ) :
        $popPanel.css( "bottom", $wrap.outerHeight() - $( window ).scrollTop() - $.mobile.getScreenHeight() + "px" );
```

This will repositon elements, which you need to add *data-fixed="top/bottom"*.

To transition-in the elements I'm using:

```
// show $popPanel
$popPanel
    // add transition class - this is using slide
    .addClass('in')
    .show('fast')
// clean up
window.setTimeout( function() {
    $popPanel.removeClass('in');
    });
```

I liked this functionality in JQM 1.0, but I think the polyfill is even better, because I'm getting by with just this one snippet vs. needing the full old-fixed-toolbars handler.